# How to chain multiple automatic responses to make for Linux build?

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, shell, make

Currently I have a script capable of selecting the cpu subarchitecture for a Linux build, but selecting native leads to an infinite loop for selecting `P6_NOPS` Intel cpus. I there anyway to send the second argument as well with bash or another scripting technique?

```
#  1. AMD Opteron/Athlon64/Hammer/K8 (MK8)
#  2. AMD Opteron/Athlon64/Hammer/K8 with SSE3 (MK8SSE3)
#  3. AMD 61xx/7x50/PhenomX3/X4/II/K10 (MK10)
#  4. AMD Barcelona (MBARCELONA)
_subarch=

if [ -n "$_subarch" ]; then
        yes "$_subarch" | make oldconfig
```